# How to apply formatting string when binding DateTime to MaskedTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, binding, format, maskedtextbox

I have a `MaskedTextBox` using the mask `"00/00/\2\000"` to restrict input to a format of `XX/XX/20XX`, with the `Text` property bound to `MyBindingSource.SomeProperty` of type `DateTime`.

Recently, values with a single-digit month or day recently started displaying incorrectly. I expect that the `ToString()` method is being called on the value at some point in data binding, and I believe the call is not padding month / day with zeroes.

I tried setting the format type of the `MaskedTextBox.Text` property to `DateTime` in the advanced data binding properties, but it didn't help.

How can I apply `ToString("MMddyyyy")` when converting the `DateTime` object to a string, before the value is bound to the `Text` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the binding's [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) and [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx) events to do the conversion yourself, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982261/bind-nullable-datetime-to-maskedtextbox/986666#986666)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Yet I can't help but wonder what changed to cause this in the first place. Are there any designer settings that would affect this? (VS2005)

Comment: The IncludePrompt and IncludeLiterals properties would be a good place to start.